# How to break a word without cut the word on css

Tags: css

**I want to a title like this**

> Lorem ipsum dolor amet cray thunder cats ramps
>
> chicharrones yuccie prism anim next level
>
> pork belly banh mi incididunt

**But this is what i got**

> Lorem ipsum dolor amet cray thundercats ram
>
> ps chicharrones yuccie prism anim next leve
>
> l pork belly banh mi incididunt

I tried `word-break: break-all;`

What should i put to make it happen ?

Thank you

Comment: text-align: justify;  should be working

Comment: thx u sir it worked

Comment: good luck and choose my best answer

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshots imply that either CSS, HTML Tags or HTML Entities force hyphenation.

Check if your text contains `<br>`, `<wbr>` or `&shy;` and remove them.

Declare `hyphens: normal;` to stop breaking words in generally and `word-wrap: break-word;` to break words which are wider than the containing box.

Answer (score 0):

`text-align: justify;` should be working

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.